# unable to connect to novnc via nginx-ingress + HA proxy

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, novnc

I've set up a novnc container running Kali and host it a k8s service type `NodePort`. I'm able to access Kali through novnc using `<master-node-ip>:<service-port>`.
[access novnc using ip address + service port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbyMi.png)

I'm trying to host the service on a customized URL using nginx-ingress + HA proxy.

When I access novnc using the URL, it shows the message `something went wrong, connection is closed`. 
[access novnc using url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cG1Lz.png)

I've tried the same method to host a simple webpage without issue, this issue only happens for novnc services.

These are the YAML files for the deployment:

*Create namespace*

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: training
  labels:
    name: training
```

*Network policy*

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: training-netpol
  namespace: training
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  ingress:
  - ports:
    - port: 6080
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          name: training
```

*Deployment*

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kali-deployment
  namespace: training
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kali-vm
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kali-vm
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kali-vm
        image: josephsim/kali-novnc
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6080
```

*Service*

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kali-svc
  namespace: training
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: kali-vm
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 6080
```

*Ingress controller*

```
    apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      name: ingress-controller
      namespace: training
    spec:
      rules:
      - host: test.kali-vm.training.com
        http:
          paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: kali-svc
              servicePort: 6080
```

I have also point the IP address of HA Proxy machine to the URL using `/etc/hosts` file.

I'm using for this setup: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=chwofyGr80c

I'm using bare metal kubernetes cluster. 
Any idea on how to make this work?

---

EDIT:
Tried using `ConfigMap`, the same problem persist.

*ConfigMap*

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: tcp-services
  namespace: training
data:
  6080: "training/kali-svc:6080"
```

Comment: Have you tried to use this: [Kubernetes.github.io: Ingress-nginx: Exposing tcp udp services](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/)?

Comment: I have tried adding the ConfigMap. Doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: I've managed to reproduce your setup and I stumbled upon the same issue. The connection issues occurred when I tried to connect either via `haproxy` or `nginx-ingress` or both simultaneously. There was no issues when I connected via `nodePort`. Nginx logs showed: `GET /websockify HTTP/1.1" 404 206`. I assume this is happening because of the `haproxy` and `nginx-ingress` between you and the cluster. Please tell if you've managed to solve it.

Comment: Sorry sir, I still have not find a solution for this issue. I tried to move the HA proxy inside the cluster by setting up HA proxy on the master node, doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: i have same iisue. seems i will need to run guacamole within the same cluster and connect with VNC instead of http